# JAVA Xpath expression to return null when attribute not found

Tags: java, xml, xpath

In the following xml sample

```
      <employee>
        <payment contractType="1">
          <income type="0">
            <gr amount="2063.00" kae="211" code="1" />
            <gr amount="400.00" kae="215" code="6" />
            <et amount="47.55" kae="292" code="4012501" />
            <et amount="105.21" kae="293" code="4052000" />
            <de amount="88.15" code="4003101" />
          </income>
         </payment>
      </employee>
      <employee>
        <payment contractType="1">
          <income type="0">
            <gr amount="70.00" kae="213" code="4" />
            <gr amount="1560.00" kae="211" code="1" />
          </income>
       </payment>
    </employee>
```

i need to  get the value of  "amount" for "code" = "4". If the income node does not contain such data ( gr with code = "4") i need to return something like null or boolean false. Purpose is to look through all the employees in the xml file, load them on an Arraylist with 0 if they dont have any amount with code 4 else load the amount value.

code i use for this part :

```
    public class ReadXMLfile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("E2015_1_1.xml"));

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();


    expression = "/psp/body/organizations/organization/employees/employee/payment/income[@type='0']/gr";
    nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    ArrayList<String> gr4incomeList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

          String acode = (String)nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("code").getNodeValue();
          System.out.println("acode = '" + acode + "'");

               if (acode.equals("4")){
                    System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("amount").getNodeValue());
                    gr4incomeList.add(nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("amount").getNodeValue());
                    System.out.println("array = " + gr4incomeList.get(i));
        }else
                    gr4incomeList.add("0000");

    }

     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Problem is it writes "0000" in the arraylist for any gr found except the ones with code = "4".

I am really stuck.

Any ideas? Thank you guys!

Comment: gr4incomeList.add("0000"); if you want to write "0", shouldn't u be using  gr4incomeList.add("0");

Comment: Can there be more than one item with code="4", or just one?

Comment: @JLRishe only one item with code="4" per employee. Thank you

Comment: @nafas i need to store it as a 4 digit string, thanks

Comment: @Bonzay it seems ur code only works for employess that have code="4" as their first <gr> tag. am I right?

Comment: @nafas, yes the xpath expression i use goes through all the gr nodes. If it finds a code=4 it stores the value of "amount" otherwise for every gr it finds stores '0000' in the array. Think the problem is in the xpath expression. i tried to use "/psp/body/organizations/organization/employees/employee/payment/income[@type='0']/gr[code='4']" but that way i couldn't get the "empty" records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
XPathExpression exp = xpath.compile("/employees/employee");
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)exp.evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
XPathExpression grexp = xpath.compile("payment/income/gr[@code='4']");
XPathExpression amexp = xpath.compile("payment/income/gr[@code='4']/@amount");
for( int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i ){
    Node item = nodeList.item( i );
    Object resexp1 = grexp.evaluate( item, XPathConstants.NODE );
    if( resexp1 != null ){
        String resexp2 = amexp.evaluate( item );
        System.out.println( resexp2 );
    } else {
        System.out.println( "0000" );
    }
}
```

produces, for the XML snippet as shown:

```
0000
70.00
```